# Making room for TrueCrypt in front of Boot Camp Windows partition

Tags: osx-lion, boot-camp, truecrypt

Windows on Boot Camp can run from an encrypted disk, such as TrueCrypt.  However, TrueCrypt needs a very small space (less than a MB) in front of the Windows (Boot Camp) partition to install.  How can I create this space?